# Test rendering in Phoenix/Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a view module in my phoenix application that contains `render_footer/1`. How would I go about testing this function using [EXUnit](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/ex_unit/ExUnit.html)?

```
defmodule Lorem.LayoutView do
  use Lorem.Web, :view

  def render_footer(conn) do
    render __MODULE__, "footer.html", conn: conn
  end
end

defmodule Lorem.LayoutViewTest do
  use Lorem.ConnCase, async: true

  test "render_footer" do
    flunk "Not implemented!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `Phoenix.View.render_to_string`. Also keep in mind that your templates are all precompiled as `render/2` calls, so I would simply call

```
render LayoutView, "footer.html", assigns
```

Instead of the `render_footer` function, unless you need to do a bunch of assigns prep. For testing, you can do:

```
import Phoenix.View
test "render_footer" do
  render_to_string(Lorem.LayoutView, "footer.html", ..) =~ "copyright"
end
```